# Pytest live logging with parallel execution - possible?

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

I have a test suite that I run with

```
python3 -mpytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG ...
```

on the build server. The live logs are useful to troubleshoot if the tests get stuck or are slow for some reason (the tests use external resources).

To speed things up, it is possible to run them with e.g.

```
python3 -mpytest -n 4 --log-cli-level=DEBUG ...
```

to have four parallel test runners. Speedup is almost linear with number of processes, which is great, but unfortunately the parent process swallows all live logs. I get the captured logs in case of a test failure, but I need the live logs as well to understand what is going on in real time. I understand that the output from all four parallel runs will be intermixed and that is fine. The purpose is for the committer to just check the build server output and know roughly what is going on.

I am currently using pytest-xdist, but use none of the more advanced features from it (just the multiprocessing).